# I still cannot run first andengine application

Tags: android, andengine

I'm too new for AndEngine and I can not say to much thing to tell you problem.
Code is below..

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 768;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 1280;
    Scene scene;

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        Camera mCamera = new Camera(0,0,CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        EngineOptions options = new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH,CAMERA_HEIGHT), mCamera);
        return options;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources(
            OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.scene = new Scene();
        this.scene.setBackground(new Background(15,25,35));
        pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(this.scene);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
            OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Also here is the [logcat](http://pastebin.com/cJ1rWhs0).(sorry but logcat is too long) What is the problem and solution?

Comment: have you linked the right andengine project to your project?

Comment: I think yes.. From properties..

Answer (score 2):

From your logcat you have `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.andengine.opengl.view.RenderSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion`

just try to google it... and you find possible answer on AndEngine forums:

*Please note that the Emulator in Eclipse does not work with the latest GLES2 AndEngine.*
[See here...](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post27701.html#p27293)

Comment: What about using older version? I just want to learn how to create a game.. AndEngine will be just step 1

Comment: The emulator will be very slow for most types of games. You would do well to get a low-cost tablet if that is possible for testing your games. Or consider using a different technology, such as Unity3D which can run on mobile or desktop.